# What does $B \to O$ mean in Peter Freyd's book Abelian Categories

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

I am trying to read “Abelian Categories” of Peter J. Freyd. I was reading proposition 2.12 on page 37. The author states that if $A \to B$ is an epimorphism, then $B \to O$ is its cokernel. My problem is, that I cannot find what $B \to O$ means. On page 26, he defined the zero object $O$ (“an object with precisely one map to and from each object”). Furthermore, he defines the zero map $B \overset {0} \to A$ to be the unique map $B \to O \to A$, but he doesnot mention $B \to O$ (and dually $O \to A$).  So my question is: how is $B \to O$ defined and why is it the cokernel of the epimorphism $A \to B$ ?
Can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$B \to O$ is simply the unique map from $B$ to $O$ as given in the definition of a zero object which you give ("an object with precisely one map to and from each object"). So in particular there is precisely one map from $B$ to $O$ and that is what Freyd means by $B \to O$. Same thing for $O \to A$, that's the unique map from $O$ to $A$ guaranteed by the definition of $O$ as a zero object.
By the dual of the definition of kernel on p26-7, a map $B \overset {x} \to C$ is the cokernel of a given map $A \overset {f} \to B$ if and only if $xf=0$, and for any map $B \overset {y} \to D$ for which $yf=0$ there is a unique map $C \overset {z} \to D$ for which $zx=y$. So to show that the zero map $B \overset {0} \to O$ is the cokernel of a given epimorphism $A \overset {f} \to B$, I have to show that $0f=0$, and that for any map $B \overset {y} \to D$ for which $yf=0$ there is a unique map $O \overset {z} \to D$  for which  $z0=y$.  As $f$ is an epimorphism and $yf=0f=0$, it follows that $y$ must be a zero map, so we can take $z$ to be the zero map from $O$ to $D$.  Uniqueness of this map follows since it is the only map from $O$ to $D$.

Comment: That is what it is, but what does it mean? So, how do I use it to prove that the cokernel of an epeimorphism $A \to B$ is $B \to O$ ?

Comment: @Steenis. See my edit.

Comment: Why does it follow easily that $B \overset {0} \to A$ is the cokernel of $A \overset {f} \to B$ ? I do not see it. I understand your definition of cokernel but how do you apply it in this case? How do you define $C \overset {z} \to D$ in your definition? Furthermore, is $B \to O = B \overset {0} \to O$ and why?

Comment: @Steenis Since $f$ is epic, for each $D$ is at most one $g:B\to D$ such that $gf=0$, and since we have a zero map between any two objects there is at least one... thus $g$ is the zero map $B\to D.$ And the unique map $B\to O$ satisfies the property that any zero map from $B$ factors through it uniquely... there is only one map $O\to D$ in the first place and $B\to O\to D$ is the zero map. With regard to your last question, again, there is only one map $B\to O$, and the zero map is a map $B\to O$.

Comment: @Steenis. I have edited my answer further. Hopefully together with the comment above it is now clear..

Comment: (@Both) Using both answers:

Let $A\overset{f}\to B\to D=0$. Also $A\overset{f}\to B\to O\to D=0$. 
Then $B\to D= B\to O\to D=0$ because $A\overset{f}\to B$ is epic

We have $A\overset{f}\to B\to O = A\overset{f}\to B\to O\to O = A\to B\overset{0} \to O$ (by the definition of the zero map of Freyd and hence the notation $B \overset {0} \to O$). Thus $A \overset{f}\to B\to O =0$

Let $A\overset{f}\to B\overset{x}\to D = 0$. By the above $x=0$.
Now $O\to D$ is the unique map that makes $B\to D=B\to O\to D$. Hence, the cokernel of  $A\overset{f}\to B$ is $B\to O$

Is this correct?